# What are the three bars under the kill counters for in Dota2

Tags: dota-2

What are the three bars under the kill counters for in Dota2

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the number of match wins that are needed to become the winner of a series; lit up bars represent matches already won.
In your example, each team needs to win 3 matches to win the series, which is thus a "Best of 5"; the team currently playing on Radiant has won one match, while Dire has won two.